# ws-replace is similar to ws-hole , isn't?

Tags: f#, websharper, websharper.ui.next

```
ws-replace
```

The attribute ws-replace creates a Doc or seq hole. The element on which this attribute is set will be replaced with the provided Doc(s). The name of the hole is the value of the ws-replace attribute.

```
ws-hole
```

The attribute ws-hole creates a Doc or seq hole. The element on which this attribute is set will have its ***contents*** replaced with the provided Doc(s). The name of the hole is the value of the ws-hole attribute.

---

Can you help me clearly distinguish these two concepts?

---

https://developers.websharper.com/docs/v4.x/fs/ui#reactive

Answer (score 7):

`ws-replace` replaces the *entire element*, while `ws-hole` just replaces the *contents*. Look at the examples in the [documentation you linked to](https://developers.websharper.com/docs/v4.x/fs/ui#reactive). Notice how with `ws-replace`, the `<div>` element disappears and is completely replaced by the "Welcome" paragraph. Whereas with `ws-hole`, the `<div>` element *is still there*, wrapped around the "Welcome" paragraph.

### Using `ws-replace`

```
<div ws-replace="Content"></div>
```

becomes:

```
<p>Welcome to my site.</p>
```

### Using `ws-hole`

```
<div ws-hole="Content"></div>
```

becomes:

```
<div>
    <p>Welcome to my site.</p>
</div>
```